# sending live audio recording to backend

Tags: javascript, web-mediarecorder

I am trying to send the live chunks of audio being recorded on a browser to my node js server using socket io. What I have tried so far only sends the buffer when I stop mediaRecorder but what I want to achieve is to send the live chucks every certain kilobyte. How can I achieve this?

```js
const socket = io();

const recordButton = document.getElementById('record');
const stopButton = document.getElementById('stop_rec');

let userId;

socket.on('connect', () => {
  userId = socket.id

  socket.on(userId, (msg) => {
    console.log('Message from server:', msg);
  });

  recordButton.addEventListener('click', async() => {
    audioStream()
  });

  stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    doneSpeaking()
  });
});

let mediaRecorder;

async function audioStream() {
  try {
    const constraints = {
      audio: {
        sampleRate: 16000,
        channelCount: 1
      }
    };
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    mediaRecorder.start();

    const handleDataAvailable = (e) => {
      //this sends the buffer to server after I stop mediaRecorder
      socket.emit(userId, e.data);
    };

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;

    mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
      console.log('Recording stopped');
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error accessing microphone:', error);
  }
}

function doneSpeaking() {
  if (mediaRecorder && mediaRecorder.state === 'recording') {
    mediaRecorder.stop(); // Stop the recording
  }
}
```

Comment: I've never played with this, but the docs for [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) state that the `dataavailable` event _"Fires periodically each time `timeslice` milliseconds of media have been recorded **(or when the entire media has been recorded, if `timeslice` wasn't specified)**"_. Try `mediaRecorder.start(1000);` to send data every second

Comment: @blex yep, that worked. Thanks! Mind adding it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) state:

> `dataavailable`
>
> Fires periodically each time `timeslice` milliseconds of media have been recorded **(or when the entire media has been recorded, if `timeslice` wasn't specified)**.

You can specify it in the [`start` method of MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/start):

```
mediaRecorder.start(1000); // sends data every second
```